# "Invalid assignment" error from == operator

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I was trying to write a simple method:

```
boolean validate(MyObject o)
{
  // propertyA && propertyB are not primitive types.
  return o.getPropertyA() == null && o.getPropertyB() == null;
}
```

And got a strange error on the `== null` part:

> Syntax error on token ==. Invalid
>   assignment operator.

Maybe my Java is rusty after a season in PLSQL. So I tried a simpler example:

```
Integer i = 4;
i == null;
// compile error: Syntax error on token ==. Invalid assignment operator.

Integer i2 = 4;
if (i == null); //No problem
```

How can this be?

I'm using jdk160_05.

To clarify: I'm not trying to assign anything, just do an `&&` operation between two boolean values. I don't want to do this:

```
if (o.propertyA() == null && o.propertyB() == null) { return true; }
else { return false; }
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but my guess is they think this is such a silly and obvious question it seems like you are trolling.

Comment: Earlier the question was insufficient and was able to give the answer based on that

Comment: Sorry dude, I don't want to be rude, but RTFM gives pretty obvious answer to this

Comment: Your `validate` method shouldn't have any problems as long as PropertyA and PropertyB are both objects and not primitive data types.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your first snippet, unless either propertyA or propertyB is not an object type?

Comment: @Pyrolistical They are objects, thats why i cant get it.

Comment: @Pyrolistical, snap! Less than a minute between the comments, but you did get there first.

Comment: Is there any chance you didn't use an actual equals sign but something that looks like it?

Comment: @Sugerman. Double checked, asked a team member, it was a == sign.

Comment: @Tom I am sorry, but I would seriously check the code in `getPropertyA()` and `getPropertyB()` and make sure you are not unboxing it into a primitive.  Otherwise that is impossible.  I would try your `if (o.propertyA() == null && o.propertyB() == null)` and that shouldn't compile with the same error.

Comment: @Pyrolistical. Seriously, they return a model object. Instances of a class I created yesterday (I followed your advice and checked).  I know its hard to believe. Hard enough for me to ask it here.

Comment: @Tom I would try a clean build then.  You might be getting phantom errors

Comment: The validate method as written above compiles, so ... ?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as not reproducible because your 'validate' method compiles just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are confusing assignment and equality comparison. I think your compiler is just giving you a confusing error message. This program:

```
Integer i = 4;
i ==null;
```

should give an error something like this:

```
Program.java:8: not a statement
                 i ==null;
```

Your first program should compile correctly. Perhaps there is some invisible unicode character in the text that is confusing the compiler. Try deleting the entire function and typing it in again.

Comment: Thanks for putting some thought into it and not giving the `you cant assign` crappy answer.

Comment: ? so did you fix your problem or not?

Comment: @Pyrolistical. It helped more than all the other answers.

Comment: I think Tom's question is more completely answered by my answer, but yours at least also points in the right direction.  The issue is that `i==null` isn't a statement, but some java compilers give crappy diagnostics for the "not a statement" case.

Comment: @Tom So if it helped, what was the problem?

Answer (score 9):

== is not an assignment operator, it's a boolean equality operator, see:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.2

If you want to set i to null use the simple assignment operator =:

```
i = null;
```

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.1

If you want to check that i is null then you need to use the == operator

```
if (i == null)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do then... you're question is a little confusing...

Comment: So I cant do something like `return i==null` ? Hard to believe.

Comment: Yes, you can write "return i==null;"
But that is not what you submitted us for our consideration.

Comment: `return i==null` will work. Your code above is only `i==null`.

`i==null` by itself doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: @ryanprayogo. Still, compiler error? Should just compile into a no-op or something.

Answer (score 4):

I think I see your problem.  I'm sorry the other answers don't address it.

So, Java has this idea that is shared by some other languages that just because something is a valid *expression* doesn't mean that that thing, by itself, is a valid *statement*.

For example, this code will complain similarly:

```
Integer i = 4;
i+3;    // this line gives a compilation error
```

And yet obviously I can use `i+3` (go unboxing!) elsewhere to mean "`7`":

```
System.out.println(i+3); // this is fine
```

It gets a bit confusing because unlike some languages that have this expression/statement distinction, java allows you to use any method call - whether it returns a value or not - as a statement.  However, most java operators do not - by themselves - form a valid statement.

Likewise, this fails to compile:

```
Integer i = 4;
i;    // this line gives a compilation error
```

For the full gory details, see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#32588

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL, assigning a value to a variable is done with the `:=` operator. Comparing two values is done with `=`.

In Java,  assigning a value to a variable is done with the `=` operator. Comparing two values is done with `==`, or a `.equals()` method in some cases.

You can do things like this:

```
x = i==null;
```

This will test if `i` is `null` and if so, the value `true` will be assigned to `x` (assuming that x is a boolean).